# Dynamics 365 + Custom Workflow + Entity Reference cannot have Id and Key Attributes empty

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I have 2 custom workflows. The output of one becomes the input for the another.

After I call the first custom workflow and use the output of it in another step, it gives me error:

> 'InValid Argument' error - Entity Reference cannot have Id and Key Attributes empty.

Code for 1st workflow -

```cs
public class RetrieveCaseForUnit : WorkFlowActivityBase
{
    #region Input Parameters
    [Input("Unit")]
    [ReferenceTarget(msdyn_customerasset.EntityLogicalName)]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> Unit { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Output Parameters
    [Output("Case")]
    [ReferenceTarget(Incident.EntityLogicalName)]
    public OutArgument<EntityReference> Case{ get; set; }
    #endregion


    public override void ExecuteCRMWorkFlowActivity(CodeActivityContext executionContext, LocalWorkflowContext crmWorkflowContext)
    {
        try
        {

            if (crmWorkflowContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("crmWorkflowContext is null");
            }

            crmWorkflowContext.Trace("Getting Unit Input");
            EntityReference unitRef = Unit.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext);
            if (unitRef == null)
            {
                crmWorkflowContext.Trace("Error Message : Unit value not provided");
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Unit value not provided");
            }

            EntityReference caseRef = GetCase(crmWorkflowContext, unitRef);

            if (caseRef != null)
            {
                Case.Set(executionContext, caseRef);
            }
            else
            {
                Case.Set(executionContext, null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidWorkflowException();
        }
    }

    private static EntityReference GetCase(LocalWorkflowContext crmWorkflowContext, EntityReference unitRef)
    {
        EntityReference caseRef = null;

        CrmServiceContext serviceContext = new CrmServiceContext(crmWorkflowContext.OrganizationService);
        var caseRecord = (from currentcase in serviceContext.IncidentSet
                          where currentcase.gsscore_Unitid.Id == unitRef.Id 
                              &&  currentcase.gsscore_CaseTypeId.Id == new Guid("3A152B94-D2DF-E711-A94A-000D3A30DB97")
                          orderby currentcase.CreatedOn descending
                          select currentcase).FirstOrDefault();

        crmWorkflowContext.Trace("Case Record" + caseRecord);

        if (caseRecord != null)
            caseRef = caseRecord.ToEntityReference();

        return caseRef;
    }
}
```

Code for 2nd workflow -

```cs
public class NMSGetWorkOrderForCase : WorkFlowActivityBase
{
    #region Input Parameters
    [Input(gsscore_nmsmessage.Fields.gsscore_CaseId)]
    [ReferenceTarget(Incident.EntityLogicalName)]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> Case { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Output Parameters
    [Output(gsscore_nmsmessage.Fields.WorkOrder)]
    [ReferenceTarget(msdyn_workorder.EntityLogicalName)]
    public OutArgument<EntityReference> NMSWorkOrder { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public override void ExecuteCRMWorkFlowActivity(CodeActivityContext executionContext, LocalWorkflowContext crmWorkflowContext)
    {
        if (crmWorkflowContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("crmWorkflowContext is Null");
        }


        if (Case.Get(executionContext) == null)
        {
            crmWorkflowContext.UserId = crmWorkflowContext.WorkflowExecutionContext.UserId;
            throw new InvalidWorkflowException();
        }

        crmWorkflowContext.Trace("Start");
        Guid caseId = Case.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext).Id;
        try
        {
            CrmServiceContext serviceContext = new CrmServiceContext(crmWorkflowContext.OrganizationService);
            var WorkOrderRecord = (from currentworkoder in serviceContext.msdyn_workorderSet
                                   where currentworkoder.msdyn_ServiceRequest.Id == caseId
                                   orderby currentworkoder.CreatedOn descending
                                   select currentworkoder.Id
                                      ).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

           if (WorkOrderRecord != null)
            {
                EntityReference workorderRef = new EntityReference(msdyn_workorder.EntityLogicalName, WorkOrderRecord);
                NMSWorkOrder.Set(executionContext, workorderRef);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            crmWorkflowContext.TracingService.Trace("Case record does not exist." + crmWorkflowContext.WorkflowExecutionContext.MessageName + ex.Message);
            if (crmWorkflowContext.ErrorCode == null)
            {
                crmWorkflowContext.ErrorCode = ((int)WorkflowActivityErrorCode.NMSGetWorkOrderForCaseError).ToString();
            }
            crmWorkflowContext.UserId = crmWorkflowContext.WorkflowExecutionContext.UserId;
            throw new InvalidWorkflowException();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the first workflow is actually providing an output?

Comment: why don't you go step by step, like remove the second step having 2nd WF activity, debug the 1st WF activity to see whats coming in caseRecord & caseRef ? Trace should have given you some idea already..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorkOrderRecord record is a GUID.  It can't be null.  `if (WorkOrderRecord != null)` should be changed to `if (WorkOrderRecord != Guid.Empty)`

Answer (score 1):

If this is registered as a custom action called in a workflow, it is likely that you have specified an output entityreference arguement as required, but your workflow is returning null. Check to see if any of your action output variables are required. If so, set them to optional, save, publish, update plugins and try it then.  This fixed the error for me. The problem wasn't the code, it was the action expecting something to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar case with the same error message can be if you do not initialize output argument of `EntityReference` with null value before exiting `Execute` method:

```cs
[Output("Found salesorder")]
[ReferenceTarget("salesorder")]
public OutArgument<EntityReference> Salesorder { get; set; }

...

Salesorder.Set(executionContext, null); /* you need this initialization */

if (isSalesOrderFound)
{
  Salesorder.Set(executionContext, so);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.